# Getting two list of outputs into one text file

Tags: python, loops

I made two list where they are each sorted based on score, either descending or ascending, where I want only the top 10 highest and top 10 lowest together in one output file as a textfile.

currently my code looks like this in a textfile:

```
###ordering them after 10 highest and 10 lowest

with open("scoresextreme.txt", "w") as f:

    sorted_score = sorted(Scores_extreme, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    sorted_score_1 = sorted(Scores_extreme, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=False)

    print("Top 10 highest scores")

    for item1, item2 in sorted_score[:10]:
        print(f'{item1} \t {item2}')
        line = ' '.join(str(x) for x in ({item1}, {item2}))
        f.write(line + '\n')


    print("Top 10 lowest scores")

    for item3, item4 in sorted_score_1[:10]:
        print(f'{item3} \t {item4}')
        line = ' '.join(str(x) for x in ({item3}, {item4}))
        f.write(line + '\n')

f.close()
```

I wanted the script to print both the top 10 highest and top 10 lowest, as well as put them both into the new file.

But only the top 10 highest are printed and not the top 10 lowest, also only the highest appear in the new textfile "scoresextreme.txt".

Anybody know what i should do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly functional. Both highest and lowest scores get printed and appear in the text file.

Make sure the Scores_extreme list looks something like `[['name', 1], ['name2', 2], ...]`.

If the first list is printed, the second list has be printed as well.  Maybe you haven't saved your .py file, so you are running an old version without the top 10 lowest code?

Comment: No im running the code written here and the scoresextreme.txt only consist of the top 10 highest :((

Comment: @ChristinaHChristiansen try deleting scoresextreme.txt

Comment: I made two list looking exactly the same for Scores_extreme, gave each top 10 its own, then it worked.

i dont know if this file maybe got changed when used in the top 10 highest, but it works if i just create two list with exactly the same in them.